# Parent category can't be deleted

Tags: php, mysql

Okay So here is my category-subcategory table which looks like this:

```
cat_id | cat_name | parent | cat_status | parent_id 

1      | Mens     | --     | Active     | 0   

2      | Womens   | --     | Active     | 0

3      | Shoes    | Mens   | Active     | 1
```

Question :

Okay Now I delete `"Mens"` category directly, it should be prompt that you can' delete Mens, you need to delete first subcategory containing `"Mens"` (Here in my case, I need to delete Shoes First).

Comment: So what is your error?

Comment: Just now! if I delete "Mens"  it allows me to delete it, but it should be prompt that " I need to delete its subcategory" then and then only i cn delete it...

Comment: So before deleting any record check if it's is not the children of other category and if it exist then prompt it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check existing subcategory availability before delete action.
You can make ajax call and check if sub category exists "SELECT cat_id from table WHERE parent_id = ?"
If you found result you can alert or prompt to user that sub category is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with a foreign key referening same table id

EX;

create table category_demo(
cat_id int auto_increment NOT NULL ,
parent_id int DEFAULT NULL,
label varchar(100) not null default '',
primary key (cat_id),
foreign key (parent_id) references category_demo(cat_id) on delete RESTRICT on update cascade
);

Insert the root category with parent id as NULL.

Then whenever you delete the parent category and it has a corresponding child category it will return you Foreign key constraint error

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d65f/1)